# Stuck on Copy Finished, Not able to take production build

Tags: ionic3, angular5, angularfire2

I have an issue with angularfire2 and ionic 3.  Based on the documentation https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/v3.md implemented the fetching of data from firebase and its working very good in **ionic serve**.

When I took the production build **ionic cordova build android --prod**, Terminal stop execution at copy finished and after an hour it alerting that the Javascript out of memory.

I removed the angularfire2 package from package.json and try to take production build after **npm install**, it working without any issues.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
  "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
  "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^4.7.0",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
  "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
  "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
  "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.6.5",
  "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
  "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.0.5",
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.19",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
  "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.2",
  "firebase": "^5.0.4",
  "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
  "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.0.0",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "run": "1.4.0",
  "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
  "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.26"
},
```

Is there anyway to solve the issue ?

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 6.0.1 
OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/jishad/android-sdk-linux/
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ionic cordova build ios --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release
```

Source: [Link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1426)

Comment: ionic cordova build ios --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release  which means this is same as production build ?

Comment: Not exactly but it does a pretty good job at minifying the js and css as the --prod does. It also enhance the application speed

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help dude, its working perfectly now.

Comment: @Dude, The app is not able to install in device, I tried to copy the apk from pc to mobile and open the apk with package installer. Its showing App not installed.

Comment: Roll-down your Firebase to version 4.6.2 and AngularFire2 to version5.0.0-rc.4.
This will restore all to normal

Comment: Sign apk and able to run in android.

Comment: @Jishad Cheers dude

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic app-scripts has compatibility issue with angularfire, firebase. To make life easy, use this command.**

```
 ionic cordova run android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release
```